# How to display items across single row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display categories across a single row in my home page but they stack on top of each other instead.

```
<div class= "container">

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
   <% Category.take(6).each do |category| %>
  <%=link_to category.name, categories_show_path(category: category.name)%>
   <% end %>
</div>
  </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create a row and col according to your requirement, also provide more information so someone can help you solve your problem, you're trying to display 6 categories name in `col-md-3`, I have updated your code you can check out

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class='row'>
       <% Category.all.take(6).each do |category| %>
         <div class="col-md-2"> 
           <%= link_to category.name, categories_show_path(category: category.name) %>
         </div>
       <% end %>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```